# Screen Saver settings completely missing in Big Sur?

Tags: macos, big-sur, system-settings, screensaver

I am running macOS Big Sur Version 11.2.1 on a M1 Mac Mini.

When I try to access my screen saver settings in System Preferences > Desktop & Screen Saver > Screen Saver, I now get a blank window like so:

[image]

Comment: I'm running Big Sur on an intel iMac and the Screen Saver window looks fine. Maybe its due to your M1  chip. It did take about 30 seconds for the window to populate.

Comment: Works here on M1. Did you have custom screen savers installed?

Comment: Nope. Nothing other than default. I noticed my monitor stopped going to sleep a few days ago and went to look at the settings.

Comment: I have the same problem. Fresh install, Mac mini M1, MacOS v 11.2.3.